# pip exists, says no module named pip

Tags: python, pip

I have `pip` installed and can clearly see the file (by using `which pip`) but, when I go to actually run a command like `pip install -r requirements.txt` (or even just `pip` to get help), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I get this whether I'm using pip 2 or 3. What is going on here? Any way to fix it without reinstalling the whole thing?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment (venv).

Comment: Yes I am. I can easily move on by just making a new virtual env but I want to know what's going on under the hood

Comment: Have you activated the environment? I missed that a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succinct answer - I ran `pip -m site` to see where my site packages are, and poked around in there and couldn't find pip. It must have gotten deleted...

This makes me wonder, though, why did pip disappear when I ran `pip install --upgrade pip` as **it instructed me to do**!

Answer (score 1):

Force a reinstall by running

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
python -m pip <action>
```